# AWS Lambda - Deploy in 2 environments with nextJs

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, next.js, serverless

I am using nextJs with AWS Lambda. (https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-nextjs-plugin)

When I deploy in production I am just doing: `serverless`

File `serverless.yml` is:

```
// serverless.yml

nextApp:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.15.1"
```

It creates 2 folder `.serverless` and `.serverless_nextjs`.

I want to have the possibility to deploy in 2 different environments.

For example

`serverless --prod` => will deploy in Production in AWS

`serverless --dev` => will deploy in Dev in AWS